# Javascript parse array into input parameter

Tags: javascript

I have dynamic array (object)

```
var variables = {};

variable["var1"] = someValue;
variable["var2"] = someValue;
...
variable["varN"] = someValue;
```

and how I can put it into this fce:

```
$("#uploadForm").ajaxSubmit({
   data: { variables }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("#uploadForm").ajaxSubmit({
   data: variables 
});
```